# Background Location Updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios13

I am building an app with location services.

I am using users current location to get objects around user. Which is currently working perfectly. The only problem is, I want to create local notifications for user with "signficantLocationChanges" on background but when app launches from `AppDelegate` with `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` function, `launchOptions` object is `nil`.

I want to get background updates and make an HTTP API request and depending on response, I will create local notification.

Here is my `AppDelegate` class:

```swift
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: LocationManager?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Checking this because if the app is started for location updates,
        // no need to setup app for UI
        if let _ = launchOptions?[.location] {
            locationManager = LocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            locationManager?.getCurrentLocation()
            return true
        }

        attemptToRegisterForNotifications(application: application)

        if #available(iOS 13, *) { } else {
            app.start()
        }

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: LocatableOutputProtocol {
    func didGetCurrentLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in
            if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"

                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)", content: content, trigger: trigger)

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { _ in

                }
            }
        })
    }

    func failedGetCurrentLocation(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    private func attemptToRegisterForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to get auth", error)
                return
            }
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } else {
                print("NO AVAIL FOR NOTIFS")
            }
        })
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }
}
```

Also I have an custom `LocationManager` class:

```swift
import CoreLocation

final class LocationManager: NSObject, Locatable {
    weak var delegate: LocatableOutputProtocol?

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager

    override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()

        let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            if (authStatus == .authorizedAlways || authStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse) {
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            } else {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                print("we dont have permission")
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    func getCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let coordinates = locations.first?.coordinate {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            self.delegate?.didGetCurrentLocation(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.delegate?.failedGetCurrentLocation(error: error)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("status changed")
        if (status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse) {
            print("we got permission")
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to debug this with creating new schema on Xcode with `Wait for executable to be launched` and using Freeway Ride on Debug menu of Simulator. Also tested with real device.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you enabled Location Updates in Background modes? Once you enable that your app should get updates in background. Also, i don't see [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges] called anywhere. Without this being called your app will not get significant location updates.

Comment: @PuneetSharma it is called at LocationManager class. Also yes, it is enabled.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @CyberMew actually yes but I have abandoned project because of pandemic...

Comment: @onurgenes that’s unfortunate… for posterity sake would you be able to share how you fixed it and what was the cause?

Comment: @CyberMew I have added the final code to this gist: https://gist.github.com/onurgenes/8e339de3103712ac836b97f57421b5cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@onurgenes, If you add a real code from your project, first of all, how you can start any location updates from here?

```
    if let _ = launchOptions?[.location] {
        locationManager = LocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.getCurrentLocation()
        return true
    }
```

When app start at for the first time `launchOptions` will be `nil`, and your `LocationManager()` even not started, so your any location monitoring and updates will not work (maybe you have the some code at `app.start()` but now it looks like an error).

The second thing - at your sample, you are using bought of locating monitoring:

```
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

so here your location manager handles only `significantLocationChanges()`. If you want to use both of them - you should toggle it (at `didBecomeActiveNotification` and `didEnterBackgroundNotification`) or create different instances of the location manager as Apple recommend.

The third - your problem. Let's look for this part more detailed:

```
locationManager = LocationManager()
locationManager?.delegate = self
locationManager?.getCurrentLocation()
```

As I mention up - at `LocationManager()` you start monitoring location:

```
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

and this is what you need - significant location changes. But after you call `getCurrentLocation()` with `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` so you 'rewrite' your monitoring, and that's the reason why you did not get any updates from it.

Also, take in mind:

1. Significant locations deliver updates only when there has been a
   significant change in the device’s location, (experimentally
   established 500 meters or more)
2. Significant locations very inaccurate (for me sometimes it up to 900 meters). Very often significant location use just for wake up an application and restart
   location service.
3. After your app wake up from location changes
   notification, you are given a small amount of time (around 10
   seconds), so if you need more time to send location to the server
   you should request more time with
   `beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:)`

Hope my answer was helpful. Happy coding!

Comment: I have tried all suggestions but this is still not working. I can invite you to my GitHub repo if you are available.

Comment: @nurgenes sure, my username at github is rubikva

Comment: sent invite. you need server for this project but you can mock the server responses.

Comment: "create different instances of the location manager as Apple recommend." <- can you link to the source for this?

Answer (score 2):

@onurgenes You need to use `NotificationCenter` on your location manager initialize section like below,

```
import CoreLocation

    final class LocationManager: NSObject, Locatable {
        weak var delegate: LocatableOutputProtocol?

        var locationManager: CLLocationManager

        override init() {

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackgroundActive(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForegroundActive(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            super.init()

            let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                if (authStatus == .authorizedAlways || authStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse) {
                    locationManager.delegate = self
                    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
                    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                } else {
                    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                    print("we dont have permission")
                }
            } else {

            }
        }

        func getCurrentLocation() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            if let coordinates = locations.first?.coordinate {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                self.delegate?.didGetCurrentLocation(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)
            }
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            self.delegate?.failedGetCurrentLocation(error: error)
            self.locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            print("status changed")
            if (status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse) {
                print("we got permission")
            self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            } else {
                print("nope")
            }
        }
    }


        @objc private func applicationDidEnterBackgroundActive (_ notification: Notification) {
                self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }

        @objc private func applicationWillEnterForegroundActive (_ notification: Notification) {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
```

You need to use this LocationManager class on your AppDelegate class for it's initialize. I hope it will help to achieve your required output.

Comment: still no luck. If you want, I can invite you to my GitHub repo.